# 40 votes won't trigger the Vox Populi badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, votes, badges

In my profile I can see the following track of the vox populi badge:

[image]

However, if I want to vote a question, I get the message:

[image]

Is there sort of a restriction to this badge?

Comment: This has happened before.  People have (speculatively) provided many possible explanations: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=vote+limit+answer+25  The answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279730/166924 is particularly clear concerning the (twisted) voting logic.

Comment: @whuber It seems twisted to me, indeed. So I reckon I could undo a couple of non-question-votes and see what happens? Or «stuff is set in stone» already for today?